# What's the best approach to find out in doing what a Linux OS process is stuck?

Tags: linux, database-performance, strace, perf

Oracle DBA here! No experience at all in troubleshooting Linux performance...

I need to identify the bottleneck in an Oracle database running on Oracle Linux. The same procedure runs fine on other VMs, so the problem is specific to a specific VM (different hosting).

For what I got from Oracle diagnostic tools, my process gets stuck for seconds apparently doing nothing related to the SQL world: I see an event indicating "wait on CPU" on the running session and Oracle tracing shows a long time gap from purging some materialized view logs and the next query, so I need to find out what is going on during that time frame where Oracle trace gives no details about the ongoing DB activity.

What can you suggest to do for tracing a given PID using pre-installed Linux performance tools? I'm trying to figure out how to use `perf`, but it's quite complex.

Comment: Observing what an application and a Linux system is doing can happen at many levels, each with different  tools and/or specific arguments for more generic tools. These diagrams list quite a few them : http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html

Comment: One option : cat /proc/<PID>/stack